# Condensing down a 3 dimensional numpy array into a 2 dimensional

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to do a matrix multiplication with two numpy arrays, one is a 2x2 and the other I want to treat as a 2x1, but there is a third dimension due to a linspace variable. This makes it not possible to apply the transformation as I intend

The code:

```
import numpy as np 
t = 0
delt = 0
theta = 0
n = np.linspace(0,1,0.1)
E_z = np.exp((t - n) * 1j)
E_y = np.exp((t - n - delt) * 1j)
QW = np.array([[np.cos(theta)**2 + 1j * np.sin(theta)**2, (1 - 1j) * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(theta)], 
                  [1j * np.cos(theta)**2 + np.sin(theta)**2, (1 - 1j) * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(theta)]])
QW = np.multiply(QW, np.exp(-(pi/4) * 1j))
E = np.array([[E_y],[E_z]])
E = np.dot(QW, E)
```

The error received is

"ValueError: shapes (2,2) and (2,1,14) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 1)"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: we can't run your code because you have `self`, `t` etc in it. It's also unclear as to what you're trying to achieve

Comment: The error is probably produced by the last line, the `dot`. That function expects the last dim of `QW` to match the 2nd to the last of `E`.  Are those the expected dimensions for those variables?  You should have a clear idea of what array dimensions are at each step.  Print `shape` periodically to verify your intuitions.  Test pieces interactively if needed.

Comment: @RockyLi,  sorry, was moving from my code to here, put in values for the variables, sorry bout that

Comment: @hpaulj Is there a better function to use then?

Comment: Do you want that `E` to be (2,1) or (2,14)?

Comment: I want it to be (2,1)

Comment: Why use the linspace variable?

Comment: It’s part of a bigger code where I’m plotting and animating a 3d em wave. The line pace is so I can evenly space vector bases along the x axis

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is in the line

```
E = np.array([[E_y],[E_z]])
```

This tells numpy that you want to stack 2 10 x 1 arrays hence yielding the 2 x 1 x 10. Leaving out the inner-brackets yields a 2 x 10 array. For future reference, the .squeeze method can be used to remove inner 1 dimensions.

```
import numpy as np 
t = 0
delt = 0
theta = 0
n = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
E_z = np.exp((t - n) * 1j)
E_y = np.exp((t - n - delt) * 1j)
QW = np.array([[np.cos(theta)**2 + 1j * np.sin(theta)**2, (1 - 1j) * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(theta)], 
                  [1j * np.cos(theta)**2 + np.sin(theta)**2, (1 - 1j) * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(theta)]])
QW = np.multiply(QW, np.exp(-(np.pi/4) * 1j))
E = np.array([E_y,E_z])
E = np.dot(QW, E)
```

Comment: Will this still apply the transformation correctly I t he at I want?  Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: As long as you want the dot product between QW and E yes. Additionally, the original code used linspace, but it had the wrong third argument. That function takes (start, stop, num). I think you meant arange  which takes (start, stop, step)

Answer (score 0):

the QW dimension caused the problem you can try this

```
QW = np.multiply(QW, np.exp(-(pi/4) * 1j)).reshape(2,2,1)
```